# How do I notate a polynomial with Stirling coefficients and what properties do I need to prove it?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, stirling-numbers

I have a group of polynomials where each term increases in degree and has coefficients that appear as Stirling numbers of the second kind:

$1: 1 \\ 
2: 1+x \\
3: 1+3x+x^2 \\
4: 1+7x+6x^2+x^3 \\
5: 1+15x+25x^2+10x^3+x^4 ...\\$

How can I represent consecutive polynomials in closed form and what properties of Stirling numbers and/or polynomials do I need to prove the nth polynomial with induction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Hint:** These polynomials are called *[Touchard polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touchard_polynomials)*
>   \begin{align*}
> T_n(x)=\sum_{k=0}{n \brace k}x^k\qquad n\geq 0
> \end{align*}
>   and you might want to use 
>   \begin{align*}
> T_{n+1}(x)=x\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}T_k(x)
> \end{align*}
>   for induction.